# Getting java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException excetion in Play Application

Tags: java, curl, playframework-2.0, netty

I am working on a play application which allows client to upload large tar.gz files . i

To give an example , user can use this curl command to upload a file name "testfile.tar.gz".

```
    curl -v -F "corpusFile=@testfile.tar.gz" -F "description=Large File Test" API_ENDPOINT
```

When a user to try to upload a really large file like around 3GB . It always fails returning this error :-

curl: (55) Send failure: Connection was aborted

Also the exception which I see in play server logs :-

```
     java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:409)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.writeFromUserCode(AbstractNioWorker.java:127)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:99)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:725)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:71)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59)
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:87)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.sendDownstream(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:428)
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$play$core$server$netty$PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$handle$1$6$$anonfun$13.apply(PlayDefaultUpstr
```

eamHandler.scala:210)
         at

I am using Play 2.2.1 version. I have tried setting max length size in application.conf and also setting request timeout but that does not seem to help . 
I added the following lines in my application.conf file :-

```
    #Max Length
    parsers.text.maxLength = 10024K

    #Request Timeout
    ws.timeout=1200000
```

If other people who faced similar issue or have idea what's going on here , that would be great help .

Answer (score 0):

3 GB is a large file to upload and it requires time. So increase your curl's execution time. Add this parameter as well.

```
-m 1200000
```

or

```
--max-time 1200000
```

Here values are in seconds.